# Messaging from ViewModel to View is not handling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, messaging

I looked through lots of articles about it, but somehow, it is still not working.

In the View, in constructor, i have

```
Messenger.Default.Register(this, Constants.MY_MESSAGE, delegate(string s)
            {
                DoStuff();
            } );
```

In the ViewModel, i have

```
Messenger.Default.Send(Constants.MY_MESSAGE);
```

Thats it, i just need to send a notification to the View, no additional data. But somehow, DoStuff(); never rises. Debugger just moves further to the next line after Send();

Maybe i should force it to deliver exactly to my View? 
Is there any shortcuts/list with tips about mvvm light messaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crap. I spent several hours, trying to figure out answer. Correct sending is

Messenger.Default.Send(String.Empty, Constants.MY_MESSAGE);

Comment: How to debug this crap? Now i'm trying just to repeat same stuff: same registering, same sending, but View is not getting message :(